# python ctypes: get pointed type from a pointer variable

Tags: python, pointers, types, structure, ctypes

I have a structure which contains primitive fields (int, uint8, ...) and also pointers.
These pointers often point to an array of different structures type in order to keep a deeply nested structure.
For example in C:

```
struct A
{
 int field1;
 int field2;
 struct B *fields3;
 unsigned int countofb;
}

struct B
{
  int anotherfield1;
  int anotherfield2;
}
```

In python with ctypes I create a wrapper of the structures A and B.
iterating over `_fields_` of structure A I reach the third field `field3` and I get a ctype variable of type `LP_struct_B` .

The question is, is there a way, a function, a method of ctypes that convert a pointer to the pointed type ?

I need something like

```
a=A()
st=pointedtype(a.field3) # or also st = pointedtype2(LP_struct_B)
#desired output: st = struct_B
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok.
I've empirically found the answer.
Simply use the attribute `_type_` of the variable or of the pointer type

```
a=A()
print a.fields3._type_ # struct_B
tipo=type(a.fields3) # tipo=LP_struct_B
print tipo._type_ # struct_B
```